GASでフォームの回答を設置したい
GoogleFormをテスト形式にしています。
正解の設定をGASから行いたいのですが、どのような指定になるのでしょうか？
対象の質問項目は
const Form = FormApp.openBy(ID);
const items = Form.getItems();
items[n]**********

にて指定したいのですが ****** の部分がわかりません。
正解の設定は、質問の選択肢を番号で指定したいです。
（ラジオボタンになっています）
よろしくお願いします。


正解の設定は、質問の選択肢を番号で指定したいです。
（ラジオボタンになっています）

以下のようなラジオボタンのリスト形式の既存の選択肢に対して、番号(インデックス)で正解を設定する方法を説明します。


items[n]********** にて指定したいのですが ****** の部分がわかりません。

items[index].asMultipleChoiceItem() で選択肢を MultipleChoiceItem として取得できます。
ここで、選択肢の一つを正解として設定できれば良いのですが、そのようなメソッドは用意されてないようです。Choice.isCorrectAnswer() で正解かどうかの取得はできるようです。
選択肢の作成時のみ正解の設定ができるようです。

createChoice(value, isCorrect)

よって、既存の選択肢をもとに新しく選択肢を作成、作成時に正解を設定し、既存のものを置換してやります。
以下がコードの例です。
const answers = [3, 3, 2]; で、順に問題毎の正解をインデックスで与えています。
function myFunction() {  

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();

  // 選択式回答のリスト 選択肢のインデックスを保持
  const answers = [3, 3, 2];
  // フォームから各アイテムを取得
  const items = form.getItems();

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  {
    // 質問をラジオボタンとして取得 (質問の形式によって取得方法が異なる)
    const multipleChoiceItem = items[i].asMultipleChoiceItem();    

    // ポイントを設定する場合
    multipleChoiceItem.setPoints(1);     
    
    // 回答の選択肢を取得
    const choices = multipleChoiceItem.getChoices();

    // 回答となる選択肢のインデックスを取得
    const answerIndex = answers[i];

    // 既存の選択肢に対して正解を設定できないので
    // 選択肢を再作成し、再作成時に正解を設定する
    const newChoices = [];

    for (let j = 0; j < choices.length; j++)
    {
      // 既存の選択肢をもとに選択肢を作成、作成時に正解の場合は、正解として設定
      const newChoice = multipleChoiceItem.createChoice(choices[j].getValue(), answerIndex === j);
      newChoices[j] = newChoice;      
    }

    // 再作成した選択肢で選択肢を置換
    multipleChoiceItem.setChoices(newChoices);    

    console.log(`itemIndex: ${i}, title: ${multipleChoiceItem.getTitle()}, answerIndex: ${answerIndex}`);
  }  
}


Googleフォームの事前回答のフォームの出力方法はわかりますか？
事前回答URLを発行するとどの記入欄がどのエントリーパラメータが割り当たっているか確認できます。
https://blog.nakachon.com/2016/12/22/how-to-add-url-parameter-for-google-form/
このページの中盤で解説されています。

ご回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。
